# Opening excel file (e.g. C:\xxx\xxx/.xls) in Catia

Tags: catia

I am really new in vba and i would like to ask how can i open specific excel file (xxx.xls) in Catia by macro. Thank you for your help in advance.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

use the catia filesystem object as below

```
Dim FileSys
Set FileSys = CATIA.FileSystem

Dim xlApp 
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim mydoc 
Set mydoc = xlApp.workbooks.open("Add the file path here")
```

Comment: Don't forget..In the VBA Editor to Goto Tools-> References  and select **Microsoft Excel... Object Library**